# Find string in PDF/a documents

Tags: pdf, document, scanning

I'm scaning several documents and save as PDF/a in directory. Is it possible and how (which software) search string inside documents.

For example in one of documents I have string **stackoverflow**

After type stackoverflow I want focus on this documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

1. Convert pdf in searchable pdf eg. (PDF Converter Professional 8)
2. Put all document in one folder
3. Open foxit reader in right corner click on small directory icon and set search location and enter your string.
4. Enjoy!